# Connectivity manager in android

Tags: android, networking, connectivity

Greeting!!

I have an issue ,I used a Connectivity manager class to get the network status.The class is working ok in 90% android devices but its not working in some devices.

Look at my code .Posted below-

```
    public class Connectivity {
    public static boolean isConnected(Context context){
        boolean found=false;
        ConnectivityManager manager=(ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo network=manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (network!=null && network.isAvailable() && network.isConnected())
            found=true;
        return found;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isConnectingToInternet(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure above code will work in all devices(sdk>=16).Coz i do not have any specific mobile and scenario where my code is not worked.It happened some of client devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isDeviceConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

A small change in your code will definitely help you...